# Custom control, background doesn't change

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworks

So I made a custom control, containing a button and an image. I create 64 of them, a chessboard.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
    {
        Square field = new Square(i, j, this);
        field.Click += OnFieldClick;
        squares[i - 1, j - 1] = field;
        squares_list.Add(field);
        Square_control fieldBase = new Square_control(field);

        this.table.Children.Add(fieldBase);
        Grid.SetRow(fieldBase, j - 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(fieldBase, i - 1);
    }
}
```

Square is a class inheriting from Button class. It's background is set in it's constructor.

`Square_Control` is my custom control containing a button and an image. Its constructor sets the button to the parameter.

Thanks to the debugger, I found out that colors black and white are set properly in the field and `fieldBase` objects, but when I run the program all the buttons are white.
I feel like I'm missing some important knowledge about how WPF works.

`Square` constructor:

```
public Square(int row, int col, MainWindow wind)
    {
        if ((row + col) % 2 == 0)
            isWhite = true;
        else
            isWhite = false;

        colName = col;
        rowName = row;

        if (this.isWhite)
            SquareColor = wind.BasicWhite;
        else
            SquareColor = wind.BasicBlack;

        Background = SquareColor;
        window = wind;
    }


BasicWhite = new SolidColorBrush(new Color()
        {
            R = 255,
            B = 255,
            G = 255,
            A = 255
        });

        BasicBlack = new SolidColorBrush(new Color()
        {
            R = 0,
            B = 0,
            G = 0,
            A = 255
        });
```

Square_control xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="SQR">
    <Image x:Name="FigImage"/>
</Button>
```

It's constructor:

```
public Square_control(Button butt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SQR = butt;
    }
```

Also, I tried setting background color in Square_Control directly in XAML and it worked.

Comment: You'd have to provide us with the `Square` class code so we can try to help

Comment: 'This' is the MainWindow.

Comment: What are BasicWhite and BasicBlack?  For all i know both could have the value of the same color assigned (white).

Comment: I will edit post

Comment: I did use debugger, and background colors are set properly.

Comment: Isn't `A` transparency in %? Which would mean both your colors are **255% transparent** hence fully transparent? (I even think it's worse like **25500%**)

Comment: @Rafalon, no. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.a.aspx

Comment: Okay, my bad I read something on rgba in css and it's not the same

Comment: No, R, G, B and A are bytes. There are no problems with colors. I tried them with basic buttons and they worked.

Comment: For troubleshooting your problem: Reduce your test program to only one button, as this makes the following debugging method much easier to use. In your Shape and Shape_Control classes, override the OnPropertyChanged method ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.onpropertychanged.aspx)), and include an assert that stops the debugger whenever the background property has changed. This way you can track when the background property changes to whatever new value, and hopefully find the cause of your problem.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is only quick'n'dirty debugging that you should remove again after finishing with troubleshooting. Normally, you would almost never override OnPropertyChanged (see remarks in the documentation i linked to in my last comment)

Comment: The problem is, if you ask me, in Square_control. How do you add your Square to it? What is Square_control's XAML?

Comment: Post is updated

Comment: I just did the debbuging. Funny, all colors are set properly. It seems that Square_Control ignores the fact that buttons are set in the constructor, and shows basic ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing it properly indeed.

First, you already have a `Square` control; what do you need a `Square_control` for?

You don't even need `Square`; just make a new `UserControl` and put your `Button` and your `Image` in it.
If you need further specialization (like the `IsWhite` property), you can just add it to this `UserControl` as dependency properties.

And simply pass the required parameters (x, y) to its constructor.

You can start with something like that:

```
public partial class ChessSquare : UserControl
{
    public enum Piece
    {
        King,
        Queen,
        Rook,
        Bishop,
        Knight,
        Pawn,
        None
    }

    public readonly SolidColorBrush BasicWhite = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { R = 255, G = 255, B = 255, A = 255 });
    public readonly SolidColorBrush BasicBlack = new SolidColorBrush(new Color { R = 0, G = 0, B = 0, A = 255 });

    public Boolean IsWhite
    {
        get { return (Boolean)this.GetValue(IsWhiteProperty); }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(IsWhiteProperty, value);
            this.Background = value ? BasicWhite : BasicBlack;
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsWhiteProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(IsWhite), typeof(Boolean), typeof(ChessSquare), new PropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnIsWhitePropertyChanged)));

    public Piece PieceType
    {
        get { return (Piece)this.GetValue(PieceProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(PieceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PieceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(PieceType), typeof(Piece), typeof(ChessSquare), new PropertyMetadata(Piece.None, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPieceTypePropertyChanged)));

    public ChessSquare(int row, int col)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IsWhite = (row + col) % 2 == 0;
    }

    private static void OnIsWhitePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var square = (ChessSquare)d;
        square.Background = (bool)e.NewValue ? square.BasicWhite : square.BasicBlack;
    }

    private static void OnPieceTypePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // change the image, set it to null is the value is Piece.None
    }
}
```

And eventually replace the `this.Background` by `this.button.Background`, depending on how you name stuff in this UserControl's associated XAML.

Comment: Thanks, I was overthinking and complicating the problem. Ockham's razor is always the best. I wish I knew why my solution didn't work though.

Comment: @Jarek It seems that you can't replace "placeholder" controls in code behind. The debugger will tell you that you did, but the actual visual tree will not be modified.